# Silverlight F# library and WCF

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, wcf, f#

I have a WCF service(maybe multiple services) and a client in Silverlight(C#). As I read somewhere on the web F# is great for async and parallel programming. I want to give F# a try and write a library that communicates to given WCF service, handles it's faults and returns result.
 
Are there any benefits of doing so, except learning new language and func programming?

Comment: What sort of benefits are you thinking there might be?

Comment: Less boiler plate code, maybe more simple and maintainable code.. don't know, that's why I'm asking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, I think F# can be quite useful for asynchronous programming in this scenario. If you want to write your asynchronous code properly, you need to use `BeginFoo`/`EndFoo` methods or you need to use event-based API to avoid blocking the UI thread when performing some asynchronous call. As a result, you cannot write code in the usual sequential style - just by doing one operation after another. Instead, you need to wrap everything in callbacks that contain separate exception handling.

In F#, you can use asynchrornous workflow that hide all the "callbacks" and automaticaly wrap everything in exception handlers. As a result, you can write asynchronous code that does multiple calls as a sequential code and use all usual control flow constructs (such as `try`, `for`, `while`, ...). You can write:

```
let processData(userInputs) = async { 
  try
    let! temp = Service.AsyncDoSomething(userInputs)
    let! res = Service.AsyncDoSomethingElse(temp)
    return res
  with e ->
    // Handle exception
```

This calls the `DoSomething` operation asynchronously and moves the rest of the function into a callback that gets executed when the operation completes (and similarly for `DoSomethingElse`). However, the exception handling can be written in the usual way. The feature is also nice for writing some user interface interactions (see for example [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2985783/drag-and-drop-in-silverlight-with-f-and-asynchronous-workflows) or the recording of my [F# talk at London User Group](http://skillsmatter.com/podcast/open-source-dot-net/tomas-petricek-reactive-programming-in-fsharp))

The disadvantage of using F# for this project that it doesn't have any direct support for WCF. You can certainly use it, but you'll have to write C#-style mutable classes, which doesn't look that nice - a good option may be to use a C# library and define the usual necessary WCF stuff there (and then just use it from F#).

Comment: Thanks for answer, I think I can write all the connection logic to WCF in C# lib and expose the factory that will create channels to F# lib and do data processing in F#. What can you recommend to read to get up and running with F# in the shortest amount of time?

Comment: @Viktor If you have C# background, but none or little functional experience, then my book was written for you: http://manning.com/petricek. There have been quite a few questions about learning F# on StackOVerflow, so you can check out http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bf%23%5D+books. F# Dev Center also has links to learning materials (that includes some shorter online free tutorials): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/fsharp/cc835246